# Test Functions and positiveness of a functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ such that for every **nonnegative** test function $\phi\in C^0_c(\Omega)$ 
$$ \int_\Omega f\phi\geq 0.$$
How can one proof that $f\geq 0\;\;a.e$?

Comment: Try contradiction. What would happen if there was a subset of $\Omega$ with non zero measure such that $f<-\epsilon$ in that subset, for some $\epsilon>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: WLOG $f\in L^1(\Omega).$ Find $g_n \in C_c(\Omega)$ such that $|g_n|\le 1$ on $\Omega$ and $g_n \to \text { sgn }(f)$ a.e.

Comment: Can you actually assume integrability if $\Omega$ is not $\sigma$-compact?

Comment: I assumed we were in some $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: what guarantee the existence of such sequence $\{g_n\}_n?$